# How to increase the fault tolerance of the connection between on-premise and VPC in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I came across this question in my AWS study and feel confused about the original answers, any enlightening is appreciated:

> A company has configured and peered two VPCs: VPC-1 and VPC-2. VPC-1
>   contains only private subnets, and VPC-2 contains only public subnets.
>   The company uses a single AWS Direct Connect connection and private
>   virtual interface to connect their on-premises network with VPC-1.
>   Which two methods increase the fault tolerance of the connection to
>   VPC-1? Choose 2 answers

```
Options:
A.  Establish a hardware VPN over the internet between VPC-2 and the on-premises network.
B.  Establish a hardware VPN over the internet between VPC-1 and the on-premises network
C.  Establish a new AWS Direct Connect connection and private virtual interface in the same region as VPC-2
D.  Establish a new AWS Direct Connect connection and private virtual interface in a different AWS region than VPC-1.
E.  Establish a new AWS Direct Connect connection and private virtual interface in the same AWS region as VPC-1
```

Correct Answer

```
B. Establish a hardware VPN over the internet between VPC-1 and the on-premises network
E. Establish a new AWS Direct Connect connection and private virtual interface in the same AWS region as VPC-1
```

My question is why we don't need to set up a connection between the two VPCs? will it help to provide fault tolerance if do? since there is a peering between VPCs already, will A and C help the link between on-premise and VPC-1 in this case?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Answer A is wrong because there is no transitivity allowed in the VPN/peering connection.

If VPCB has VPN connection to on-premise, this will not allow VPC A to go over the same connection, just because it is peered, NO it can't.

Answer (score 0):

By default, DX Connection and VPC peering **doesn't support transitive routing** natively.

Let's understand what is transitive routing.

> - OnPrem <---DX Link---> VPC-1 <---Peering---> VPC-2

- It looks like everything is connected but its not, OnPrem can
  communicate only to VPC-1 because the way DX learns route's via
  Private VIF is through its BGP neighbour Amazon ASN(*which is defined
  by VGW and it is specific to a VPC*) and its a routing domain in BGP
  terms. So OnPrem knows only about VPC-1. **So OnPrem cant speak to VPC-2**
- Now from VPC-2, through peering it knows how to reach VPC-1 but doesn't even know how to reach OnPrem via VPC-1 because thats how VPC peering works, peer VPC's only exchange their VPC's CIDR
- Even VPN uses the same logical entity VGW(*same as DX Private VIF*) on AWS Side, So assuming its a dynamic VPN which works on BGP, now you can co-relate the way routes being exchanged between VPC's and On-prem similar to Private VIF.
- Option D is not possible because, to connect to DX directly both DX Connection location and VPC's must be in the same region.